# How to specify a local IP as apache's httpd source IP

Tags: apache, firewall, httpd.conf, listen

My `webhost` is a solaris server has many IP addresses a few are listed below.

```
$ ifconfig -a

lo0: flags=2001000849<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST,IPv4,VIRTUAL> mtu 8232 index 1
        inet 127.0.0.1 netmask ff000000
ipmp0: flags=108001000843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST,IPv4,IPMP,PHYSRUNNING> mtu 1500 index 2
        inet 10.61.15.6 netmask ffffff00 broadcast 10.61.5.255
        groupname ipmp0
ipmp0:1: flags=108001000843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST,IPv4,IPMP,PHYSRUNNING> mtu 1500 index 2
        inet 10.61.15.142 netmask ffffff00 broadcast 10.61.5.255
ipmp0:2: flags=108001000843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST,IPv4,IPMP,PHYSRUNNING> mtu 1500 index 2
        inet 10.61.15.143 netmask ffffff00 broadcast 10.61.5.255
ipmp0:3: flags=108001000843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST,IPv4,IPMP,PHYSRUNNING> mtu 1500 index 2
        inet 10.61.15.144 netmask ffffff00 broadcast 10.61.5.255
.....
```

I have an apache instance on webhost that acts as proxy and forwards the request to `remotehost` port 11130

The issue is that the firewall team as allowed connectivity only from this source IP `10.61.15.6` on `webhost` to destination `remotehost` port 11130

When i hit the remote application using apache frontend URL

https://mywebhost.mybank.com/remote/health.ping

It works only when the apache soure IP is `10.61.15.6` as the firewall is open and it fails if i keep retrying (refreshing) as the apache httpd source IP changes to others like `10.61.15.142`

How can i enforce that the apache httpd https port 443 source IP is always `10.61.15.6` when it connects to any remote host port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache httpd documentation is generally thorough, but you have to know your way around. It's organised by module, so in this case we want [the page for mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html).

Looking down that page, I believe the directive you are looking for is ["ProxySourceAddress"](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#ProxySourceAddress):

> Set local IP address for outgoing proxy connections 
> ... 
> This directive allows to set a specific local address to bind to when connecting to a backend server.

So within your top-level httpd.conf or a `<VirtualHost>` block, you would write this:

```
ProxySourceAddress 10.61.15.6
```

Comment: your solution works but can u tell me how can we specify the source IP `10.61.15.6` for telnet command just like how we did for apache httpd ?

Comment: @Ashar That sounds like a different question completely, but typing `man telnet` would be the best place to start. Also, try installing `netcat`, which may be more suited if you're just connecting to arbitrary ports and not actually running the old telnet protocol.